# Nodejs array indexof function usage

Tags: arrays, node.js, random

I'm trying to develop a random category Id generator function on nodejs. Firstly, I receive all the existing category Id's from my database and push them into a array then I generate a random integer(between boundaries) and I compare the random number with my cat id array. I use indexof() function to make the comparison but it always return true; What may be the problem. Here is my code;

```
var random = require("random-js")
var selectCategoryID = "SELECT id from category.category";
var catIdresult = client.querySync(selectCategoryID);
var catIdArray = [];
    catIdresult.forEach(function (row) {
        var catId = row.id;
        catIdArray.push(catId);
    });

    var randomNum = new random()

    var K = randomNum.integer(16777000, 16777999);

   if(catIdArray.indexOf(K)){
       console.log("Error, the id is : " + K);
   }
    else {console.log("Success, the id is : " + K)}
```

Comment: Should be `if(catIdArray.indexOf(K) < 0)`

Comment: nope same result as it is mentioned below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function returns the first index of an item inside an array or `-1` if it didn't find the item. So your code should do this:

```
if (catIdArray.indexOf(K) === -1) {
   //insert into db
}
else {
   //error
}
```

You can also get all IDs by using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
catIdArray = catIdresult.map(function(cat) {return +cat.id});
```

Comment: now the program always run the else statement even if it finds a match

Comment: @FatihAktepe updated the answer, there was an error in the `if` :)

Comment: now always run the if statement :) . I dont have any id between 16777200-16777217. When I write the random boundaries as these numbers (so there will be no id in my catIdArray as the numbers between these boundaries) the program always run the if statement. Basic thing I want to do is, if the program finds a match ,it should return error if not it should return success. So I can insert successful ids to database

Comment: @FatihAktepe if the item is not in the array, `indexOf` will return `-1`

Comment: maybe you have type issues. the array may contain integers and the argument you pass to `indexOf` may be string

Comment: I receive existing ids from my database. It returns the result as an object. I push them to array. I couldn't push the database result as an integer to the array. How can I do that?

Comment: @FatihAktepe you're selecting IDs from the result of your query. If the IDs are string, you need to convert them to integer. I've updated my example with `map`

Comment: I've solved the issue in a different way.Now I receive the max existing id number from database then I increase it and create new id for new entry.